# Over a field of characteristic $p>0,$ do all non-separable morphisms have degree divisible by $p$?

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I'm looking for a result that must be known: Do all non-separable curve morphisms over a field with characteristic $p>0$ have degree divisible by $p$? I couldn't find this exact result being stated, but it is heavily implied by this proposition in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves:

> Every map $\psi: C_1 \rightarrow C_2$ of smooth curves over a field of characteristic $p > 0$ factors as
> $$C_1 \xrightarrow{\quad\phi\quad} C_1^{(q)} \xrightarrow{\quad\lambda\quad} C_2,$$
> where $q = \deg_i(\psi)$, the map $\phi$ is the $q^{\text{th}}$-power Frobenius map, and the map $\lambda$ is separable.

The proposition assumes that the inseparable degree is a $q=p^n$, a power of the field characteristic. I'm assuming there is a result that says so.

Comment: [Purely inseparable extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_inseparable_extension).

Comment: An extension of degree prime to $p$ is indeed separable.